# Azure Setting Source IP not working

Tags: azure

I have a Redhat Virtual Machine

In my Network > Inbound rules

I want to open TCP port 5814 from only specific IPs and it's not working

If I have inbound as Any then I can hit the site

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that source IP is configured like this x.x.x.x/32 and destination IP must be your private IP y.y.y.y/32, not your public IP. You can go to Network Watcher on Azure portal and run a test that guarantee any rules are blocking your, also you can have a look at IP flow. Another option you must consider is to verify any firewall rules inside your Virtual Machine (like iptables). You NSG must be associated either to your subnet or NIC of virtual machine.

[More details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8l6F.jpg) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565103/port-3389-wont-open-up-on-azure-vm/61565731#61565731)